# Laravel upload image from API

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to upload an image using the API. Even though, after running the first test, the database just stored the directory and not the file-name, worst part, it stored all directories that come before the one that is needed to store the image.

[image: What is being stored]

The code I'm using for the store is the following one:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $image = $request->file('image');

        if($image == null){
            $imagesDir = 'subjectImgs/';
            $images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
            $fileDir = $images[array_rand($images)];
            $path = $fileDir;
        } else {
            $path = $image->storeAs('uploads/images/store/',  $image->getClientOriginalName(), 'public');
        }

        $subject = new Homework([
        'subject_id' => $request->subject_id,
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id, 
        'title' => $request->name,
        'image' => $path,
        'progress' => $request->progress,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'duedate' => $request->date
        ]);

        $subject->save();

        return response()->json([
        "code" => 200,
        "message" => "Homework added successfully"
        ]);
    }
```

I'm uploading from a mobile device, I believe this info is also important (?) Same issue when in the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

You are saving `$path` into `$subject->image` that is equal to `public_path() . '/uploads/images/store/';`. You should add `$file->getClientOriginalName()` if you want the filename :

```php
$subject = new Homework([
   ...
   'image' => $path . $file->getClientOriginalName(),
   ...
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are settings `'image' => $path,` and before that `$path = public_path() . '/uploads/images/store/';` which yields the expected results.

Now if you want to only save from a form input, you can use the following code:

```
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $path = $image->storeAs('uploads/images/store/',  $image->getClientOriginalName(), 'public');
```

Where 'public' is the default public filesystem as described in the doc here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: This seems to work, but when I try to upload an image from mobile, nothing gets stored.

Comment: Everything is happening on server-side in this code, try to debug the frontend regarding your mobile issue

Comment: Let me upload the updated code I got. I've tried to debug using Insomnia (its better than postman), still it didn't store the image. It's now the code the one that is troubling.

Comment: have you run the command `php artisan storage:link` before using the `public` filesystem?

Comment: Yup,I did run it

Comment: Can you share your blade template? maybe there is an issue there

Comment: I'm not using blade, I'm using react-native as my frontend, I'm making use of the API in a mobile app.